# Expand Square View to Fill Rectangular Superview Using Auto Layout

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder

In one of my view controllers I have a square control that I want resized based on the user's device.  The app will always run in portrait.  I have an aspect ratio constraint on the control to keep it square.

I have the control embedded in a container UIView.  The container has constraints attaching it to the left and right edges of the content view and constraints spacing it from other controls above and below the container.  Depending on the iPhone model, the container view can have longer top/bottom sides than left/right sides (iPhone 4), or it can have longer left/right sides than top/bottom sides (iPhone 6).  I want the square control to be horizontally centered, pinned to the top of the container, and I want it to expand to fill the container view, yet keep it's aspect.

As far as I can tell, I cannot pin the edges or some constraints will break, yet when I only pin the top, the control shrinks to nothing.  I have played around with compression resistance on the control but that had no effect.

If there's a solution without the need of the container view, that's fine.  It just seemed like it would be easier to control with the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Situations like this can often be solved by pairing an equality constraints at a reduced priority with an inequality at required priority.

So, for example, a constraint that the square's leading edge equal its superview's leading edge at priority 900 and a constraint that the square's bottom edge is less than or equal to its superview's bottom at required priority.

When the superview is taller than it is wide, the leading edges will be able to coincide, so that constraint will be satisfied and the bottom will be less than the superview's bottom, so that constraint will be satisfied. When the superview is shorter than it is wide, the square will not be able to grow once its bottom coincides with the superview's bottom, because that's a required constraint. The constraint for the leading edge will be broken, which is OK because it's not required, but the auto layout system will still try to get as close as possible, which is what makes the square as large as will fit.

By the way, compression-resistance and content-hugging priorities are only relevant for view's which have intrinsic size and only related to that intrinsic size. A container `UIView` has no intrinsic size, so those priorities are irrelevant.